# PostreSQL: Link people and addresses by year

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, key

I building my first PostgreSQL database. It covers where people lived and worked over several decades (1890 to 1930). I have people, address, and restaurant name tables. The people moved around, both their residences and places of work.

**How do I establish the link to say from a person to the address for certain years?** In other words there might be from 1 to ~20 years (some people stayed put), but I'll want to query for each year (actually it's going to become a map).

I understand that if it were only once, it would be a foreign key.

I'm also going to be linking restaurant names to various addresses. In some cases I only have the names of the owners, so I'll have a link by year and whether they were employees or owners. I'll tackle that one next. Maybe with the first question answered I'll see my way to this one.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a m:n relationship qualified by date. That's typically implemented with a "join table".

e.g. given:

```
create table person (
    person_id integer primary key,
    ...
);

create table address (
    address_id integer primary key,
    ...
);
```

you might write a table like:

```
create table residence_period (
    person_id integer references person(person_id),
    address_id integer references address(address_id),
    moved_in date not null,
    moved_out date,
    constraint moved_in_before_moved_out
      check (moved_out is null or moved_in < moved_out)
);
```

You could use a `daterange` type instead of two fields if you preferred.

If you want to assert that someone didn't have multiple overlapping residences you can use an [exclusion constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.

Can I make a third table with just year and reference that? The year is often imprecise as it comes from city directories. So probably the date on the directory represents the previous years information.

Comment: @Greg Yes, of course. That'll work fine too. The general principle is the same. You can store an approximate duration in another field, the origin of the information, or whatever other data makes sense to keep track on the association between a person and a place.

Comment: The dates won't be continuous. For example I may have an address for a person in 1900 and 1901, but then none for two years, then another address for 1904, etc. So I plan to store link each person-address by year. I haven't decided how to deal with the gaps. This will end up on a map and I plan to have a scroll bar for year or similar or maybe a line with year annotations with dashed lines where the information is questionable. Most of what I'm doing is new to me, and I'm studying mapping now. So it's back and forth with the data, db, and mapping. I assume it will take several iterations.

Comment: Ran out of characters:

So I'll work on it with a year table and see how that goes for now. The answers here give me enough go forward and import into mapping apps (actually using PostgreSQL with PostGIS extension [or whatever it's called]). I'd already verified that I can see the addresses mapped in QGIS. QGIS probably isn't the final app, but it's a start.